# Evaluation && operator in C

Tags: c, logical-operators

While I was making a program in C, I came across a problem. && is not evaluating the second operand, if first is false. I know this is known as short circuit behavior. But I want second operand to be executed, see the code below to know why?

```
while(a-- && b--){
    //some statements
}
```

Please tell me different ways to accomplish my task. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what do you expect to see and what result are you getting ?

Comment: Actually if the first operand is false, I also want the value of b should be decremented. But it is not decrementing. I have to use decremented value of b after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

If a and b are small enough such that a*b doesn't overflow:

```
while( (a--) * (b--) )
{...}
```

If they can be large:

```
while( ((a--) ? 0xf : 0) & ((b--) ? 0xf : 0) )
{...}
```

Comment: The second version converts all positive numbers to 0xf and then performs a bitwise &.  So if both (a--) and (b--) are positive, then you get 0xf & 0xf which is 0xf so the loop continues.  If either one are 0 then you get 0xf & 0 which is zero and the loop stops.  Because there is no short circuiting, (a--) and (b--) are both evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using postfix decrement, the whole thing can be rewritten as simply

```
while (a && b)
{
  --a; --b;
  //some statements
}

--a; --b;
```

(Whether you really need that last line is for you to decide.)

But if you really want to keep everything stuffed into that `while` condition, there are different ways to achieve that as well. For example, you can replace `&&` operator with `&` operator as long as you remember to "normalize" the operands with `!!`

```
while(!!(a--) & !!(b--)){
    //some statements
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(a && b){
     a--; b--;
     //some statements
}
// just after loop ends
a--; b--;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the execution of second operand whether `a` is `true` or `false` then you can use comma operator. I think you need this:

```
while((b--, a--) && b) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need decremented `b` after the loop, why not just make it first to guarantee evaluation?

```
while (b-- && a--)
```

Of course, this might not work if `a` and `b` are more complicated than your question indicates.